# git won't work over webdav with https, only over ssh

Tags: git, https, webdav, synology

I set up a git server on my Synology NAS, but I can't access it over https. Previously I got the well known curl bug, and I couldn't authenticate. I replaced curl with a newer version in my git program files and this problem is now solved. But now I get the error that my repository is not found.

using git with ssh works:

```
ssh://Steven@192.168.0.6/volume1/git-repos/git-project
```

but with the following repository-url it doesn't work:

```
https://Steven@192.168.0.6:5006/volume1/git-repos/git-project
```

When I try to push, I get the error: "repository ... not found." I already tried running running hooks/post-update and 'git update-server-info' on the server, but it doesn't change a thing.

I really need https-support because I have to access the git-server outside of my local network, and I don't want to make my NAS publicly accessible through ssh. These are my first experiences with git, so I hope someone with a little more experience can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running a really old version of git, the webdav protocol is no longer the default, because it was a bit of a bad idea, and super slow.

You can tell git to use the dumb protocol, but executing the following first:

```
export GIT_SMART_HTTP=0
```

At least... I hope... Assuming it's still supported in recent versions.

Comment: Maybe I just have to make my ssh really secure. I didn't knew this was considered standard for git these days.
Maybe it is caused by the NAS itself? Normally not, because I shared the folder and I can access it with a webdav browser, but bitbucket works perfectly, so the problem must be server-side.

Comment: SSH is pretty standard... but the smart http protocol is used by sites such as github and bitbucket. This is _not_ webdav.